# tableView(_: cellForRowAtIndexPath) is not called and TableView doesn't show any data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.1

I put a Table View Controller and embed in to a Navigation Controller on IB. After that I create a WalletsTableViewController class with the following code:

```
class WalletsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var wallets = [Wallet]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchWallets()
    }

    private func fetchWallets(){
        let managedObjectContext = AppDelegate.managedContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Wallet> = Wallet.fetchRequest()
        do {
            wallets = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
        return wallets.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WalletCell", for: indexPath) 
        let wallet = wallets[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = wallet.name
        return cell
    }
}
```

I implement a persistent application that's why I have the fetchWallets() method and it works well. I can print the data to the console but the tableView doesn't want to show my elements. Moreover the implemented tableView() methods are not called. 
How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:** tableView.reloadData() did not help

**EDIT2:** Here's my storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

Comment: Mmm. try this: When you get wallets call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Add tableView.reloadData() after this line: "wallets = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)" then try to run your project

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help

Comment: Well, in your viewDidLoad add: tableView.DataSource = self and tableView.Delegate = self. Maybe tableView lose the reference for some reason.

Comment: @Kevinosaurio Certainly not. An `UITableViewController` got implicitly connected data source and delegate.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `fetch` line. Are some items fetched at all?

Comment: I know, but "maybe" before show the View the delegate and data source set it to another class "For some reason", it is unlikely but not impossible. Shared TableView for example.

Comment: Did you set the UITableViewController class to WalletsTableViewController  in Identity Inspector?

Comment: Place a breakpoint and try to print the items after fetching and see what you're getting.

Comment: Are you registering the cell?

Comment: @vadian I did this and yes, there are 2 items in the wallets array.

Comment: @Shades Yes, I set the UITableViewController class.

Comment: @Paulo Yes, I registered the cell

Comment: Have you tried changing the cells background color to see how many items are in the table view. This may alter the problem

Comment: @iPeter I tried thw following: print(wallets[0].name!) and it printed my wallets name (Purse)

Comment: Probably registering the cell in code is the problem. If the cell is designed in storyboard (no extra nib) you **must not** register the cell in code.

Comment: Please follow @vadian sir's instruction and see if the problem still persists or not.

Comment: @Paulo I tried it, but there is not any cell in my tableView

Comment: Drag a `UITableViewCell` into the table view, set the identifier to `WalletCell` and add the `reloadData` line after the fetch and you are done.

Comment: @vadian, How do you mean "you must not register the cell in code"? I did not register in code, just on the storyboard.

Comment: In storyboard the framework is registering the cell, not you. Very subtle difference 

Comment: Hmmm, so when are you trying to print the name? Unfortunately I am inclined to agree with some of the others. It sounds like the table is loading the cells before the array has been filled with data. (Edited, to remove a suggestion that was incorrect)

Comment: @Paulo Please don't suggest that. A fetch request is performed synchronously. That is not the reason.

Comment: @vadian I've tried your drag and drop suggestion, but still nothing appears :(

Comment: Can you please show your `controller`? @KrisztiánBenda

Comment: @iPeter How do you mean my controller? I showed my TableViewController class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... I did not delete the autoimplemented functions. This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments above try the following:

```
    private func fetchWallets(){
    let managedObjectContext = AppDelegate.managedContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Wallet> = Wallet.fetchRequest()
    do {
        wallets = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help

Answer (score 0):

you need to reload table view in main thread use the below code

```
   private func fetchWallets(){
        let managedObjectContext = AppDelegate.managedContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Wallet> = Wallet.fetchRequest()
        do {
            wallets = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: As mentioned above *An UITableViewController got implicitly connected data source and delegate* and `viewDidLoad` is called on the main thread so  `fetchWallets` is called on the main thread, too.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help